# Why does it look like dead pixels when I turn on light scene

Tags: light

1. I use a laptop no graphics card specifically the Asus Vivobook MA203
   2.It only happens when I turn on light scene
2. It might be caused by bad internet
3. The blender version is the 64 bit windows version 2.82

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "dead pixels". It would be helpful for people that would help you if you attach some screenshot.
Also why would bad internet affecting Blender, as you are only using it offline.

Comment: Are you using Cycles as render engine? Your "dead pixels" seam to be "light noise". You can try to increase the samples on the viewport, the light passes and the light bounces.